# Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) when calling cv.saliency_MotionSaliencyBinWangApr2014.computeSaliency( )

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv-contrib

I want to use the [cv::saliency::MotionSaliencyBinWangApr2014](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d9b/classcv_1_1saliency_1_1MotionSaliencyBinWangApr2014.html#a9c277bff61ccf265cf419b133930999b) module. My code is like this:

```py
import cv2

salCV = cv2.saliency.MotionSaliencyBinWangApr2014_create()

frame = cv2.imread(imgfile)
grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
retval, saliencyMap =   salCV.computeSaliency(grayFrame)
```

But I get error in pycharm like this:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

and like this in terminal:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What's wrong? How should I use the module cv::saliency::MotionSaliency?
Thanks!

Comment: If you're getting a segfault, then the problem is likely somewhere else than your Python code. How did you install this version of OpenCV? What exact version is it? | This also seems to be a contrib module, and those are not as likely to be well tested, so keep that in mind.

Comment: The Python code should probalby check whether `imread` succeeded (just check whether `frame` is not `None`). Won't hurt, although I think the `cvtColor` would complain first. I certainly wouldn't expect to see a sefault here in any case.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to wrong use of that class（I did not intialize it）.How to use the saliency module can refer to https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/16/opencv-saliency-detection/.

```py
import cv2

# initialize the detector
saliency = cv2.saliency.MotionSaliencyBinWangApr2014_create()
saliency.setImagesize(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0])
saliency.init()

# call the detector
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(success, saliencyMap) = saliency.computeSaliency(gray)
saliencyMap = (saliencyMap * 255).astype("uint8")
```

Comment: Link-only answers are considered not useful, since the site you're referring to may change or disappear at any point, therefore making the answer completely useless. Either write up a proper answer, describing the problem and its solution, providing the appropriate attributions to the source, or just delete this.